# Transcendence degree of a function field of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Say, $C$ is a proper, normal curve over $k$. Why is $\mathrm{trdeg}_k(K(C))=1$ ?

Here, (curve) $\dim(C)=1$ means the topological dimension is $1$ and I know that it is equivalent to the fact that supremum of Krull dimensions of open affines in $C$ is $1$. Also I know that $K(C)=O_{C,\eta}$ where $\eta \in C$ is a generic point. But how do I proceed?

Comment: Do you know that there is a nonconstant rational function on $C$? If so, this gives a morphism $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ which induces an inclusion of function fields $k(x) \hookrightarrow K(C)$. I guess that just gives transcendence degree $\geq 1$; probably [Noether normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma) is the best way to get equality.